# Synaptics Pointing Device Sensitivity too low

Tags: xorg, touchpad

I turned off mouse acceleration for my touchpad in Xubuntu on my laptop, and now the sensitivity is way too low.  I can't have acceleration because it's unusable for me that way and I also can't have the sensitivity this low.  How do I increase the sensitivity above what is allowed in the mouse settings dialogue?

Comment: What xubuntu version are you running? What are your computers specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this in your terminal:**

```
#!/bin/sh
TP=$(xinput --list --short|grep -i touchpad|cut -f 1 | cut -d" " -f 5-|sed 's/\s\+$//g')
xinput --set-prop "$TP" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5
xinput --set-prop "$TP" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 10
```